# Trying to fully remove a bluetooth device from Mavericks

Tags: mac, bluetooth

So I've run into an issue.

I had been using my bluetooth headset that I use with my laptop for a few Google Hangout calls and the quality was awful so I stopped. My problem is now that whenever I have my headset near my laptop, even if it's connected to smart phone, it constantly tries to connect every 30 seconds with my laptop!

I tried to hold Option and click the bluetooth icon and remove the device. No dice.

I tried deleting ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.Bluetooth.SOMEHEXDATA.plist, no dice.

I tried deleting /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist, no dice.

Lastly, Ive tried converting the files from binary to xml. removing the rogue headset, and converting back to binary. Again no dice. I also tried opening the plists with PlistEditPro and I see the MAC address associated with the rogue headset is also in my Audio device settings as well.

Anybody know a way to permanently unpair a bluetooth device? I've tried pretty much everything I could find.  It's just really annoying having this thing ask to connect every minute if I happen to have it near my laptop and on.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as an answer. You can then accept your own answer after some time has passed. Only then will the question be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Solution!

So, after doing some digging online, this is an apparent issue with several users and the Jawbone headsets. If you install the Jawbone Updater software, it can lead to several problems and in my case this was it.

To fully remove all traces of the Jawbone headset from your Mac, do must do the following:

- Uninstall Jawbone Updater. Just drag to trash and empty.
- Delete the jawbone file in `~/Library/Application Support`
- Delete `/System/Library/Extensions/jawbone.kext` (you must be root, or use sudo)
- Now open bluetooth settings and write down the MAC address of the device.
- Unpair the device if you have the choice (you might have to hold Option and click the Bluetooth menu icon)
- Turn Bluetooth off (Settings --> Bluetooth --> Turn Off)
- Check if the device is still cached: 
  `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist`
- it's easy to view in preview if you download PlistEdit Pro otherwise you have to
  manually convert the plist binary file to xml to view in your
  favorite text editor (`plutil -convert xml1 <filename>`)
- Don't forget, you will need to be sudo!
- If you don't see the MAC address and Nickname of your device within `<dict><key></key></dict>` tags you're in business.
- If you do, delete the opening the close `<dict>` tags with the `<key>` tags in between. There will be a lot of lines to remove. Convert back to binary if you need to (`plutil -convert binary1 <filename>`)
- Last step is to repeat the same under your local account: `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.Bluetooth.ALOTOFHEXADECIMALNUMBERSHERE.plist`
- Shutdown and reboot.
- Turn bluetooth back on, and pat yourself on the
  back for a job well done :)

If that doesn't work, message me and I'll help you out but from all the resources I've gone through today, this is what FINALLY did the trick!

Comment: Deleting the device from the Library caches will also work in the case where formerly paired devices are not entirely forgotten, but keep failing to connect. Bluetooth Setup Assistant will complain "The computer failed to pair with that" trackpad (for example). This happened to me on OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

If you *uninstalled* the driver from you computer and Bluetooth is still trying to connect to your computer, check Network and Sharing Center or some equivalent. There are a few settings you can play with.

Otherwise, configure your Bluetooth Headset.

Comment: Yeah didn't install any drivers, I did use the Jawbone update software which I've since removed. Nothing is being shared in the Sharing Center either. I tried pairing it, then removing it and it still comes back (weird because I did the same with my track pad and it doesn't do this).

Comment: Apparently Jawbone Era and Icon headsets have problems with OS X and the updater software can cause all sorts of issues from volume keys not working, to acting as malware. 

I was able to track down this thread which highlights where the other files are hidden under App Support and Extensions. I've resolved the issue by removing all traces of the jawbone software, shutting down bluetooth from the terminal, deleting the bluetooth.plist, rebooting and re-adding additional bluetooth devices.

Comment: I am glad it worked. Could you edit your initial post to add your solution ? StackExchange is a Community Site. Your Solution could be used to help further users sharing the same problem and you will get reputation points. Reputations points give some advantages and features like adding comments to other posts or creating/editing tags. You can use reputation to add bounties to your questions. I am new user as well. I have been here since 4 days. It'll be soon a week. :)

Comment: Yes definitely! I'm more active on StackOverflow than SuperUser but I'll edit it shortly.

Answer (score -1):

All it takes is 2 easy steps. Here they are:

STEP 1

Click the Bluetooth icon while holding down the "option" key.

If the Bluetooth icon isn't present, go to System Preferences -> Bluetooth -> and check the "Show Bluetooth in menu bar" box.

STEP 2

Mouse over the device name that you want removed, and click remove.

And you're done ;).